# Составить запрос к БД

Tags: php, mysql

[image: ][1]]таблица **catalog_mods**

[image: catalog]таблица **catalog**

Нужно вытащить данные о товаре из двух таблиц.

Из таблицы `catalog` вытащить `cat_id`, `cat_name` с условием - где `cat_special = 1`.

Из второй таблицы - `catalog_mods` вытащить `mod_price`, `mod_id`, `mod_parent`.

Соединять таблицы нужно через `catalog.cat_id = catalog_mods.mod_parent`.

Проблема в том, что в таблице `catalog_mods` несколько строк с одинаковым `mod_parent` для каждого товара, а надо как-то вытащить одну строку для каждого `mod_parent`, где `mod_price` имеет минимальное значение. Помогите пожалуйста составить запрос. Там как-то наверное через `INNER JOIN` и `MIN(mod_price)`. Сам пробовал такое сделать

```
$connection->query('SELECT DISTINCT cat_id, cat_name, cat_special FROM `catalog` INNER JOIN (SELECT mod_id, MIN(mod_price) as min_mod_price, mod_parent FROM catalog_mods GROUP BY mod_price) tbl_catalog_mods
                    ON catalog.cat_id = tbl_catalog_mods.mod_parent WHERE catalog.cat_special = 1');
```

получил несколько массивов такого содержания:

```
array(3) {
  ["cat_id"]=>
  string(3) "158"
  ["cat_name"]=>
  string(8) "Spread-5"
  ["cat_special"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

то есть то, что вытаскивал из `catalog_mods` в результате не выбралось

Comment: создайте, пожалуйста, на (к примеру) http://sqlfiddle.com минимальный пример ваших данных. тогда будет проще подсказать вам подходящий запрос.

Comment: вот ссылка на БД http://www.fayloobmennik.net/5512398 . Я не смог в данном Вами сервисе создать БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понял требующееся, то можно сделать такой, например, запрос:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5e73/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.10
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Хост: 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Время создания: Ноя 03 2015 г., 18:41
-- Версия сервера: 5.5.45
-- Версия PHP: 5.5.28

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- База данных: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `catalog`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog` (
  `cat_id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `cat_special` int(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `catalog`
--

INSERT INTO `catalog` (`cat_id`, `cat_name`, `cat_special`) VALUES
(1, 'name 1', 1),
(2, 'name 2', 1),
(3, 'name 3', 0),
(4, 'name 4', 1),
(5, 'name 5', 1),
(6, 'name 6', 0),
(7, 'name 7', 1),
(8, 'name 8', 0),
(9, 'name 9', 1),
(10, 'name 10', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `catalog_mods`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_mods` (
  `mod_id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mod_parent` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `mod_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mod_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `catalog_mods`
--

INSERT INTO `catalog_mods` (`mod_id`, `mod_parent`, `mod_price`) VALUES
(1, 1, 3434),
(2, 1, 1236),
(3, 1, 4567),
(4, 1, 7586),
(5, 2, 4376),
(6, 2, 3276),
(7, 2, 6482),
(8, 2, 4365),
(9, 3, 2315),
(10, 3, 3475),
(11, 3, 4597),
(12, 3, 5689);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select catalog.*, min(catalog_mods.mod_price)
from catalog
left join catalog_mods on catalog.cat_id = catalog_mods.mod_parent
group by cat_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5e73/2/0)**:

```
| cat_id | cat_name | cat_special | min(catalog_mods.mod_price) |
|--------|----------|-------------|-----------------------------|
|      1 |   name 1 |           1 |                        1236 |
|      2 |   name 2 |           1 |                        3276 |
|      3 |   name 3 |           0 |                        2315 |
|      4 |   name 4 |           1 |                      (null) |
|      5 |   name 5 |           1 |                      (null) |
|      6 |   name 6 |           0 |                      (null) |
|      7 |   name 7 |           1 |                      (null) |
|      8 |   name 8 |           0 |                      (null) |
|      9 |   name 9 |           1 |                      (null) |
|     10 |  name 10 |           1 |                      (null) |
```

Comment: Да, то, что нужно! Большущее Вам спасибо. Я читал статьи про объединение запросов, но как сам начинаю писать такие запросы, получается ерунда. Может Вы подскажите хорошую статью на эту тему?

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).